# Multivariate Gaussian Distribution for Anomaly Detection in python

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

```
X = dataframe

def estimateGaussian(X):
    n = np.size(X, 1)
    m = np.size(X, 0)
    mu = np.zeros((n, 1))
    sigma2 = np.zeros((n, 1))
    
    mu = np.reshape((1/m)*np.sum(X, 0), (1, n))
    sigma2 = np.reshape((1/m)*np.sum(np.power((X - mu),2), 0),(1, n))
    
    return mu, sigma2

mu, sigma2 = estimateGaussian(X)

print('mean: ',mu,' variance: ',sigma2)

def multivariateGaussian(X, mu, sigma2):
     n = np.size(sigma2, 1)
     m = np.size(sigma2, 0)
     #print(m,n)
     
     if n == 1 or m == 1:
        # print('Yes!')
         sigma2 = np.diag(sigma2[0, :])
     #print(sigma2)
     X = X - mu
     pi = math.pi
     det = np.linalg.det(sigma2)
     inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma2)
     val = np.reshape((-0.5)*np.sum(np.multiply((X@inv),X), 1),(np.size(X, 0), 1))
     #print(val.shape)
     p = np.power(2*pi, -n/2)*np.power(det, -0.5)*np.exp(val)
     
     return p

p = multivariateGaussian(X, mu, sigma2)
```

I am trying to apply Multivariate Gaussian for anomalies detection in dataset but I am facing some errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    148     try:
--> 149         result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
    150     except TypeError:

11 frames

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/roperator.py in rmul(left, right)
     15 
     16 def rmul(left, right):
---> 17     return right * left
     18 
     19 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

What mistakes I have done? Should I convert dataframe to matrix? I have first calculated `mean: mu`, and  `variance: sigma2` and then fit this into Multivariate Gaussian for anomalies detection but I can't fix the errors.

Comment: Did you debug the code? at which line the code breaks?

Comment: kale -> mu = np.reshape((1/m)*np.sum(X, 0), (1, n))  ->   Line 10

Comment: Try `mu = np.reshape((1/m)*np.sum(int(X), 0), (1, n))`, see if it solves the problem.

Comment: mu = np.reshape(float(1/m)*np.sum(X, 0), (1, n)) , this also works.